# How do I beat the Conquest segment in The Void Stares Back?

Tags: runescape

While playing through The Void Stares Back I ran into the Conquest part of the quest. I've tried it several times now, but I lose every single time. I've tried getting help from several videos and walkthroughs online, but the Pests don't act in the same way as in those sources and I keep losing. How do I get past this segment of the quest?

Comment: Which part of Conquest do you fail at? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @Yuu The entire thing, from start to finish. [This is how the opening board looks.](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/6/60/Pest_conquest_moving%28void3%29.png/revision/latest?cb=20121227104044)